# How to implement WPF Datagrid arrow key navigation like Tab navigation

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, arrow-keys

I have a `DataGrid` with few editable cells. Users can tab through each cells to edit the content. Now I want to implement the right arrow key working just like tab. So when a user finishes editing one cell and they press right arrow key, the focus moves to the next editable cell and starts editing.

For example, I have follow screen:

[image]

When user press right arrow key, I want my datagrid to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The DataGrid actually auto-handles right, left, up, down arrow keys. That being said, you can move the cell focus around using any of those keys and then start typing to get into the edit mode (iff the cell is editable). You don't have to listen to key press down events. Note that if you hit "Enter", then you will move to the next row.

EDIT:

Of course, by default the arrow keys won't put a cell into edit mode. Instead, you have to type in stuff or use the mouse pointer. But, you can do the following:

```
    private void myDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDataGrid.BeginEdit();
    }
```

This will force the cell on focus to enter the edit mode. I tried using key event handlers, but it seems the DataGrid won't let the user listen to the arrow keys and Enter (although you could if you use WIN32 API). Now, whenever you use any of the arrow keys, the newly selected cell will be in edit mode. Try hitting Esc to escape this mode.

Comment: Thank you for response. My datagrid is working as you said now. However, I want my datagrid cell to go straight into edit mode when it got focus. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response again. Now, my datagrid cell goes straight into edit mode. But when I finish editing one cell and press right arrow key, it still stays inside the same cell without going to the next editable cell. Can you give me some idea about that? thanks

Comment: You'd somehow have to get the caret position in the cell that currently has the focus. If it is at the end of the string in that cell, then you would have to move to the next editable cell. Right now, if you want to finish editing one cell, press 'ESC' and then use the arrow keys.

Comment: Can you give me some idea how I can make it move to next editable cell with the arrow key? Now it only moves inside the cell. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for navigation using the arrow keys

Its placed inside the Datagrid_KeyUp event

```
    DataGridCell DGcell = new DataGridCell();
    DGcell = GetCell(index, _Header);
    if (DGcell != null)
    {
         CurrentCellContentType = DGcell.Content.GetType().Name.ToString();
    }
    DataGridCell ProdCodeCell = GetCell(index, 0);
    DataGridCell DescCell = GetCell(index, 1);
    DataGridCell CostPriceCell = GetCell(index, 4);
    DataGridCell VatRateCell = GetCell(index, 9);

    DataGridCellInfo PCell = new DataGridCellInfo(ProdCodeCell);
    DataGridCellInfo DCell = new DataGridCellInfo(DescCell);
    DataGridCellInfo PriceCell = new DataGridCellInfo(CostPriceCell);
    DataGridCellInfo VatCell = new DataGridCellInfo(VatRateCell);

    string ProdCellContentType = PCell.Column.GetCellContent(PCell.Item).GetType().Name.ToString();
    string DescCellContentType = DCell.Column.GetCellContent(DCell.Item).GetType().Name.ToString();
    string PriceCellContentType = PriceCell.Column.GetCellContent(PriceCell.Item).GetType().Name.ToString();
    string VatCellContentType = VatCell.Column.GetCellContent(VatCell.Item).GetType().Name.ToString();

    switch (e.Key)
    {
    case Key.Left:
        if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBlock") e.Handled = false;
        else if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBox")
        {
            DataGridCellInfo cellLeft = new DataGridCellInfo(GetCell(index, _Header - 1));
            DgInvoiceLines.CurrentCell = cellLeft;
        }
        break;
    case Key.Right:
        if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBlock") else e.Handled = false;

        else if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBox")
        {
            DataGridCellInfo cellRight = new DataGridCellInfo(GetCell(index, _Header + 1));
            DgInvoiceLines.CurrentCell = cellRight;
        }
        break;
    case Key.Up:
        if (index != 0)
        {
            if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBlock") e.Handled = false;
            else if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBox")
            {
                DataGridCellInfo cellUp = new DataGridCellInfo(GetCell(index - 1, _Header));
                DgInvoiceLines.CurrentCell = cellUp;
                DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem = DgInvoiceLines.Items[index - 1];
            }
        }
        break;

    case Key.Down:
        if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBlock") e.Handled = false;
        else if (CurrentCellContentType == "TextBox")
        {
            DataGridCellInfo cellDown = new DataGridCellInfo(GetCell(index + 1, _Header));
            DgInvoiceLines.CurrentCell = cellDown;
            DgInvoiceLines.SelectedItem = DgInvoiceLines.Items[index + 1];
        }
        break;
```

I use a switch statement to assign a number to each column header

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, which works.

In constructor:

```
dataGridSubmissionData.KeyUp += DataGridSubmissionDataOnKeyUp;
            dataGridSubmissionData.BeginningEdit += DataGridSubmissionDataOnBeginningEdit;
            dataGridSubmissionData.CellEditEnding += DataGridSubmissionDataOnCellEditEnding;
            dataGridSubmissionData.CurrentCellChanged += DataGridSubmissionDataOnCurrentCellChanged;
```

In body class:

```
private bool isCellInEditionMode = false;

 private void DataGridSubmissionDataOnCurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            dataGridSubmissionData.BeginEdit();
        }

        private void DataGridSubmissionDataOnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs dataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs)
        {
            isCellInEditionMode = false;
        }

        private void DataGridSubmissionDataOnBeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs dataGridBeginningEditEventArgs)
        {
            isCellInEditionMode = true;
        }

private void DataGridSubmissionDataOnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
        {
            if (keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Up || keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Down || keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Left || keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                if (!isCellInEditionMode)
                    return;

                dataGridSubmissionData.CommitEdit();

                var key = keyEventArgs.Key; // Key to send
                var target = dataGridSubmissionData; // Target element
                var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; // Event to send

                target.RaiseEvent(
                    new KeyEventArgs(
                        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                        PresentationSource.FromVisual(target),
                        0,
                        key) {RoutedEvent = routedEvent}
                    );
            }
        }
```

I hope that my answer will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If your case is WPF **hosted window**, it called *Modeless WPF*.

And the solution might be this:

```
Window window = new Window();
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window);
window.Show();
```

I've seen the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870631/426315)